# Dig into an object to meets a condition and returns the property that is levels above

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Considering the following object

```
{
"objects": [
    {
        "body": "body 1", 
        "title": "Jolene", 
        "authors": [{
            "name": "Dolly"
        },
        {
            "name": "John"
        }]
    },
    {
        "body": "body 2", 
        "title": "Jolene", 
        "authors": [{
            "name": "Dolly Parton"
        }]
    }
]
}
```

My goal to verify each object `authors` property and if one of the authors `name` meets the criteria I want it to return the `body` of such object.

For instance, I want to render the `body` content of the object that has at least one `authors` `name` equal to `"John"`. In this case `"body 1"` should be returned.

I have tried with mapping and filtering but I can't figure out how to dig into each object to verify that condition and then return a property that lives in a higher level.

Please help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to search for the first match. Use `some` to check whether at least one name matches.

```js
let obj={"objects":[{"body":"body 1","title":"Jolene","authors":[{"name":"Dolly"},{"name":"John"}]},{"body":"body 2","title":"Jolene","authors":[{"name":"Dolly Parton"}]}]}

let toSearch = "John";
let result = (obj.objects.find(o => o.authors.some(x => x.name === toSearch)) || {body: ""}).body;

console.log(result);
```

If you want multiple matches, you can use `filter` and `map`

```js
let obj={"objects":[{"body":"body 1","title":"Jolene","authors":[{"name":"Dolly"},{"name":"John"}]},{"body":"body 1.5","title":"Jolene","authors":[{"name":"Dolly"},{"name":"John"}]},{"body":"body 2","title":"Jolene","authors":[{"name":"Dolly Parton"}]}]}

let toSearch = "John";
let result = obj.objects.filter(o => o.authors.some(x => x.name === toSearch)).map(o => o.body);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may look little buggy, but you definitely get a solution

```js
var obj = {
"objects": [
    {
        "body": "body 1", 
        "title": "Jolene", 
        "authors": [{
            "name": "Dolly"
        },
        {
            "name": "John"
        }]
    },
    {
        "body": "body 2", 
        "title": "Jolene", 
        "authors": [{
            "name": "Dolly Parton"
        }]
    }
]
}

obj["objects"].forEach(item=>{
  if(item.authors){
  item.authors.forEach(items=>{
          if(items.name == 'Dolly') console.log(item['body'])
      })
 }
})
```